# Stadium Seating Letters 2

Tags: texturing, materials, shaders, animation-nodes

The question is similar to [Stadium Seating Letters](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/235201/stadium-seating-letters). I have created a lot of cubes using Animation Nodes (Grid Mesh) and would like to texture all of them using a single image texture, something like this:.

[image]
(Image from [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/235204) answer by [Markus von Broady](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/60486/markus-von-broady))

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 4):

Create an empty object and use its position as texture coordinates.
[image]

[image]