# I'd like to create a material to cause my vertice-instanced objects to have their materials conform to a color ramp

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes, instances

I have a basic geo-nodes setup so that I can instance a mesh on particular verts. However, I would like the material of the mesh that I am instancing to use its position to determine what each bulb's color should be, in accordance with the color ramp (and noted by the arrow in the below image):

[image: My attempt at a material]

I already know that [I can realize instances](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/254648/how-to-assign-a-different-material-color-to-each-geometry-nodes-instance) and join everything to do this. But I'm trying to accomplish this in either the material or the geo-nodes array, if possible, so that I can quickly develop stuff without needing to realize-join-etc.

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Comment: You can't assign different materials to different instances of the same object, you need to realize the instances. You can do that automatically, non-destructively as in the link you provided, but you have to do it. [Is where a way to pass data to material without realizing instances?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/253723/60486)

Comment: And if you want to just use coordinates to differentiate color, but you want each instance to have a solid color, then you want to use snapping like here: [Stadium Seating Letters](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/235204/60486)

Answer (score 1):

did you try this setup?

[image]

i just stretched the values by the map range node.

Comment: I have replicated this node array (for the individual sphere that is being instanced). However, my results are not the same.